# Graph neural network basics

Tags: graph, pytorch, torch

I saw the following code in [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/introduction.html).

```
import torch
from torch_geometric.data import Data
edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1],
                       [1, 0],
                       [1, 2],
                       [2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.tensor([[-1], [0], [1]], dtype=torch.float)
data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index.t().contiguous())
Data(edge_index=[2, 4], x=[3, 1])
```

I understand the the code given above is a representation of the following pic,
[image]

I have an overall idea about the code except the last line of code

```
Data(edge_index=[2, 4], x=[3, 1])
```

Could you please let me know what does the line mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of edge_index in torch_geometric is `torch.Size([2, num_edges])`. For example, this graph has four edges, i.e., edge_index = [[0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 1]]. The first line of edge_index indicates the starting node of all edges, and the second line indicates the ending node of all edges. Thus, Data(edge_index=[2, 4], x=[3, 1]) means that this graph has 4 edges and 3 nodes with feature dimension 1.

Comment: Thank you. Very simple explanation. Thanks again.